# gin loads templates incorrectly

Tags: html, css, go

I have several routes in my server:

```
router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Главная страница"})
})

router.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Главная страница"})
})

router.GET("/users", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "register.html", gin.H{"title": "Регистрация"})
})

router.POST("/users", server.createUser, func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Регистрация"})
})

router.GET("/users/login", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "auth.html", gin.H{"title": "Авторизация"})
})
router.POST("/users/login", server.loginUser, func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{"title": "Главная страница"})
})
```

When I go to the /users url everything works well. But when I go to the /users/login it doesn't load styles.
in the console I have this output:

```
[GIN] 2023/03/29 - 20:06:31 | 200 |      4.4518ms |             ::1 | GET      "/users/login"
[GIN] 2023/03/29 - 20:06:31 | 404 |            0s |             ::1 | GET      "/users/static/css/styles.css"
[GIN] 2023/03/29 - 20:06:32 | 200 |    123.6236ms |             ::1 | GET      "/static/css/auth.css"
[GIN] 2023/03/29 - 20:07:04 | 200 |       3.594ms |             ::1 | GET      "/users"
[GIN] 2023/03/29 - 20:07:04 | 304 |       444.2µs |             ::1 | GET      "/static/css/register.css"
```

So when I go to the /users it loads statics correcly: static/css/file.css. But if I go to the users/login in loads static in a wrong way: /users/static/css/styles.css. Why does it append prefix "users/"?

In my html templates I have these links:

in `register.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/register.css">
```

in `auth.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/auth.css">
```

Why does it load static in different ways?

Comment: It looks like instead of "/static/css/style.css", one html file uses it as "static/css/style.css"

Comment: @BurakSerdar but what's wrong? how to fix it?

Comment: It should start with a  `/`. Without that, it is a relative path. If the page URL is `/users/login`, and the html page refers to `static/css/style.css`, it'll resolve to `/users/static/css/style.css`. Change it to `/static/css/style.css`

Comment: @BurakSerdar but i've already wrote `/static/css/style.css` in my question. Or do i misunderstood you?

Comment: The problem appears to be for styles.css. That's not what you showed in your question. What I am saying is that in one of the HTML files, you are referring to styles.css using a relative path without a `/` at the beginning.

Comment: @BurakSerdar oh, yes, you're right! I've just found that file where I wrote a path without `/` at the beginning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what was the problem. It happened because of routes: `users/` and `users/login`.
When i edited `users/login` -> `login/` everything started working as it should